# Reduce First Word in String to 3 Characters in PHP

Tags: php

I have a set of date strings in the following format:

```
$date = 'month_name DD, YYYY';
```

What I would like to do is shorten the month name to 3 characters and remove the year from the end like this:

```
$output = 'June 10, 2012';
print $output // Outputs 'Jun 10';
```

So far I have the following, but have not been able to find a method to shorten the first word:

```
print substr($date, 0, strrpos($date, ',')); // Outputs 'June 10';
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP's [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$string = 'June 10, 2012';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F d, Y', $string, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $date->format('M d'); // Output: Jun 10
```

This is a very stable way to convert times between different formats.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2XcYTZ)

Comment: In my experience it's an unknown class, but it's very useful! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tmp=explode(' ',$date);
$tmp=substr($tmp[0],0,3).' '.substr($tmp[1],-1);
echo $tmp;
```

Comment: This doesn't qualify as a help vampire for me.

Comment: Or me. Probably because it's not.

Comment: @EugenRieck Thanks, went with nickb's as I could see the date string being changed in the future; however +1 for a great answer I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = explode(" ", substr($date, 0, strrpos($date, ',')));
// first word is month, second is the date.
$date[0] = substr($date[0],0,3);
$date = join(" ", $date); // now date contains your desired result
```